# Deploy GStreamer SDK Application

Tags: c++, qt, sdk, gstreamer

I want to deploy my streaming-application wich uses Qt 5.2.1 and the GStreamer SDK and is build with Visual Studio C++ 2010.
Everything is working fine, but as soon as I want to deploy the .exe with all needed .dll's (in the sdk folder: /bin/ and /lib/ I guess..) GStreamer doesn't work anymore. The Console says that GStreamer fails to create any gstObjects.

GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT ' failed 
etc..

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that GStreamer doesn't find its plugins. It expects these .dlls in a specific folder.

You can use the environment variable `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` to point GStreamer to the right folder.    Simply call `putenv("GST_PLUGIN_PATH=path/to/plugins/)` before invoking `gst_init()`.

Alternatively according to [this thread](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Avoiding-the-GST-PLUGIN-PATH-Environment-Variable-on-Windows-td4663511.html) you can also place them into the `DIR/lib/gstreamer-1.0/` folder (with `DIR` being the output of [`g_win32_get_package_installation_directory_of_module()`](http://www.geany.org/manual/gtk/glib/glib-Windows-Compatibility-Functions.html#g-win32-get-package-installation-directory-of-module), so basically the directory `lib/gstreamer-1.0` in your app's installation directory. If you use GStreamer 0.10, modify the path accordingly)